# Baixar arquivo de requisição API em pasta do servidor (localhost) com PHP

Tags: php, libcurl

Caros amigos, tenho o código abaixo que funciona da seguinte maneira, ele faz uma requisição via cURL, me traz um arquivo, mas esta sendo necessário clicar em salvar no navegador, gostaria de simplesmente de abrir o comando e o arquivo fosse enviado para uma pasta local "/imagens no localhost, poderiam ajudar?

*** o arquivo é privado só eu utilizarei no servidor, baixarei em horários programados com uma cron e farei uma comparação futura com array_diff, não se trata de um arquivo público.

```html
<?php
 header("Content-Type: application/zip");
 header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=test.zip");

$token = file_get_contents("http://localhost/novoprojeto/token.php");
$curl = curl_init();
$imagem = "084301";

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://api/api/imagem/download-zip/$imagem",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( "Authorization: Bearer $token"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Existe algum motivo específico para você utilizar o cURL invés do `file_get_contents()` para obtenção do arquivo? Não vejo um motivo para utilizar o cURL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua pergunta está um pouco confusa, existem duas interpretações:

- Se você deseja que o cliente (quem acessa a página) baixe o conteúdo. Se este for o caso, a resposta do @Leonardo Ferreira é correta. Uma alternativa também seria de adicionar o atributo `download` no `<a>` do HTML. *O fato de está usando o `Content-Disposition: inline; filename=test.zip` leva a crer que isto seria o que procura.*
- Se você deseja baixar o arquivo para o seu servidor (isso é, baixar a imagem da API e salvar no seu servidor). Se este for o caso, veja a resposta abaixo.

---

Para baixar o conteúdo para um arquivo, utilize o `CURLOPT_FILE`

```
$imagem = "084301";

// Crie o diretório:
if (!is_dir("/imagens")) {
    mkdir("/imagens", 0777, true); // Cuidado com 0777
}

// Crie o arquivo:
$arquivo = fopen("/imagens/" . $imagem . ".jpg", 'w+'); 
// Note que é preciso saber e extensão, assumi `jpg`. Você poderá abrir o arquivo depois, sem extensão, e descobrir a extensão e renomear, mas isto é outro problema.

$token = file_get_contents("http://localhost/novoprojeto/token.php");

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://api/api/imagem/download-zip/$imagem",
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Authorization: Bearer $token"),

  // Faça o CURL usar o arquivo:
  CURLOPT_FILE => $arquivo,

  // Talvez precise alterar isto para `false`, não me recordo:
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
));


curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// Fecha o arquivo:
fclose($fp);
```

---

A ideia é obter o arquivo e salvar no `imagens/{nome do arquivo}`. Para isso, utiliza o `fopen` e depois adiciona este `fopen` no `CURLOPT_FILE`.

Comment: Olá Inkeliz, Se trata da segunda interpretação, reformulei a duvida, reescrevi meu código funcionou, Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem, vc deve trocar o header na terceira linha para o seguinte:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename=test.zip");
```

Dessa forma já irá fazer o download automaticamente.